# sftp + automated sftp by python

Tags: linux

is it possible to run the following steps via python?

my target is to automated sftp by python - login to 13.5.41.90 (Linux machine red hat 5.3)  and get from this Linux  the file.txt  , please advice?

```
  sftp 13.5.41.90 
  Password: password123
  cd /var/tmp
  get  file.txt 
  sftp> quit


  the full view from sftp command line

  sftp 13.5.41.90 
  Connecting to 13.5.41.90... 
  Password: password123
  sftp> cd /var/tmp
  sftp> get  file.txt 
  Fetching /var/tmp/file.txt to info.txt
  /var/tmp/file.txt                                                                                 100%  340     0.3KB/s   00:00    
  sftp> quit
```

Answer (score 2):

Fabric is great to do this work.

1. install fabic, refs: http://fabfile.org/

   > ```
   > pip install fabric
   > ```
2. create a fabfile.py as below:

   > ```
   > from fabric.api import * 
   > from fabric.operations import put 
   > from fabric.operations import get
   >
   > env.user = "username"
   > env.password = "password123"
   >
   > def do():
   >    put(local_path="./temp/file.txt", remote_path="/tmp/file.txt")
   >    get(remote_path="/tmp/file.txt", local_path="./temp/file.txt")
   > ```
3. run with

   > ```
   >  fab do
   > ```

Should work.:)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Paramiko library for Python. I've used it for SSH, but I know it does have an SFTP object implementation as well.

http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

Answer (score 0):

check out [pypi repository](http://pypi.python.org/). I suggest you to use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.9. It used in the [fabric](http://fabfile.org/)

Comment: The 'ssh' library on pypi is actually the latest version of Paramiko (renamed/forked).